# How to make grids covered by figures?

Tags: grid-layout, rrdtool

I am new to **RRDtool**. I generated a graph with grid(--grid-dash 1:0), a LINE(LINE1:rt#4e9a06) and I also have the area between the line and the x-axis coloured (AREA:rt#4e9a06 ). I notice the grid still shows up in the colored-area. I am wondering if there is any way to **cover the grid with the colored-area.**

Also, I am also wondering if there is any good-looking **rrdtool** samples/examples available online? Thanks.

Comment: Consider giving details to have you have done and what is your problem.

Comment: For samples, searching "rrdtool sample" on Google Image search yields many results, often with the code used to generate the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no way of testing this currently, but here's what [the documentation](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdgraph.en.html) says (emphasis mine) :

> [-c|--color COLORTAG#rrggbb[aa]]
>
> Override the default colors for the standard elements of the graph.
>   The COLORTAG is one of BACK background, CANVAS for the background of
>   the actual graph, SHADEA for the left and top border, SHADEB for the
>   right and bottom border, **GRID, MGRID for the major grid**, FONT for the
>   color of the font, AXIS for the axis of the graph, FRAME for the line
>   around the color spots, and finally ARROW for the arrow head pointing
>   up and forward. Each color is composed out of three hexadecimal
>   numbers specifying its rgb color component (00 is off, FF is maximum)
>   of red, green and blue. Optionally **you may add another hexadecimal
>   number specifying the transparency (FF is solid)**. You may set this
>   option several times to alter multiple defaults.

What about making an almost transparent grid with arguments like these (note the extra `7F` parameter which translates to 127 in decimal):

```
-c MGRID#<hex triplet>7F -c GRID#<hex triplet>7F
```

It should still be visible in the background but be invisible (or barely noticeable) once any graph covers it.

Note that [this answer](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/forum.en.html#nabble-td7157848) from the developer of RRDTool says that the grid is always painted **after** the graph, so in the end you'll always have it in the foreground, your only solution is to either totally disable it or tinker with color/transparency parameters to make it invisible when covered by the graphed data.